# Using sferik/rails_admin ,paperclip attachment field on a model simply does not apear within the admin.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rails-admin

Any simple way to make all attributes of the model to appear on the admin page?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have all necessary attributes accessible, all associations and `has_attached_file` in your model, because rails_admin will parse the forms based in your models.

Examples:

**Image in the model:**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :image
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :large => '950x400#', :medium => "250x200#", :small => "100x100>" }
end
```

**Gallery of images with association:**

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :images_attributes
  has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :reject_if => lambda {|a| a[:content].blank? } , :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and...

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  attr_accessible :gallery_id, :file
  has_attached_file :file, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

Just a note: the second approach will generate a nested form. I am trying to find a solution for it and this way came to your question. xD

Hope it helps!

Cheers!